# OpenVPN client machine as default gateway for a network

Tags: proxy, openvpn

Im trying to work out the most straight forward way of proxying the internet connections of all the devices on my network 
through to an external server.

At the moment my plan is to have a server on the network act as the client, then set that server as the default gateway on the networks DHCP server.

Are there any potential issues with this setup I am missing? If not what would be the best way to achieve it.

Comment: What os are you using for your VPN client?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea sounds reasonable. The default gateway acts as router and needs a matching routing table to send the traffic through the tunnel.

The main question is the way back.
Depending on your setup you need SNAT somewhere to make the multiple clients. It needs to be either on the server or on the client.

Additionally you need to enable ip forwarding on the VPN client and server.